# Fatal error: Class 'Exceptions\NotOwningFederationException' not found

Tags: laravel, exception

I'm following this [tutorial](https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/category/handling-exceptions-and-custom-exceptions-laravel-5-1/) to have custom Exceptions.

Everything is ok, but In my controller, When I call

```
            throw new NotOwningFederationException();
```

I get :

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Exceptions\NotOwningFederationException' not found
```

I doubled checked my files, Here is my  app/Exceptions/NotOwningFederationException.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Exceptions;


class NotOwningFederationException extends \Exception
{


}
```

I don't really know why isn't it working....

Then, in handler.php, I have a switch, that

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $code = "";
    $message = "";
    $quote = "";
    $author = "";
    $source = "";

    switch ($e) {
        case $e instanceof NotFoundHttpException:
            $code = "404";
            $message = "Not Found";
            $quote = "myquote1!";
            $author = "xxx";
            $source = "xxx";
            break;
        case $e instanceof HttpException:
            $code = "500";
            $message = "Server Error";
            $quote = "quote2";
            $author = "Morihei Ueshiba";
            $source = "";
            break;
     ....
```

Any Idea what's wrong... It seems to be obvious but I lost it....

Comment: 1) In the controller where you are throwing it - do you have ```use Exceptions\NotOwningFederationException``` at the top? 2) Ensure your auto loader (Composer or anything else) recreated the bootstrap file

Comment: The namespace needs to be `namespace App\Exceptions`. From the error message it seems this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fatal error: Class 'Exceptions\NotOwningFederationException' not
>   found

The path in the above error suggests it is looking for the class `Exceptions\NotOwningFederationException`. While your exception class is in the `App/Exceptions` directory. Laravel uses PSR-4 autoloading for it's core files, and expects the namespace to mirror the file path from the **app** directory.

Make sure your class is name spaced to correctly reflect it's file path.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

class NotOwningFederationException extends \Exception
{

}
```

When you call it in your other classes make sure you properly reference it at the top of the class.

`use App\Exceptions\NotOwningFederationException;`

Comment: Next issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716019/laravel-exception-is-not-catched-by-handler-php